# Streaming audio without wifi connection in Android

Tags: java, android, streaming

When i try to stream an audio without wifi connection my app crash: "Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side". And I want to catch the error to advice the user.This is my code that doesn't work.

```
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://ip/music/song.mp3");      
 try {

              mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


              mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);


              mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
              mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
              seekbar.setClickable(false);
          pauseButton.setEnabled(false);


   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SecurityException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: what line of the code produces the exception/error and what kind of exception/error is that?
Actually, add the stacktrace so we can find out what is wrong.

Comment: this line: mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);

Comment: what kind of exception/error does it throw?
add a catch statement to catch that kind of exception

Comment: 08-06 16:59:32.237: D/MediaPlayer(5988): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
08-06 16:59:32.240: W/dalvikvm(5988): JNI WARNING: received null jstring (GetStringUTFChars)
08-06 16:59:32.241: W/dalvikvm(5988):              in Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;.updateProxyConfig:(Landroid/net/ProxyProperties;)V (GetStringUTFChars)

Comment: i solved the problem by checking the wifi connection before streaming but i want to know if is it posible to streaming audio without wifi connection

Comment: This is not a stacktrace. If your application crashes there should be a stacktrace. There should not be a problem streaming through mobile data. Is it open?

Comment: Put a catch block for the exception you are getting and inform the user

Comment: @josiland did u solve your problem.I am also facing this similar problem

Comment: This happens if you use proxy. Remove proxy and audio will be play